# Problem with loading next level in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3D game, and I added a trigger that loads the next level with a small animation when the player goes through it. It all works fine in Unity editor, but when I build the game it does not load the next level, neither it shows the animation. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Is the scene added to the build settings? Or maybe you get an error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more detail, but in general it boils down to one of two things.  Either the trigger is not firing, or there's a problem with the script.

Try attaching something else to the trigger, maybe something that will enable a disabled GameObject in a position that would be visible when you're hitting this trigger.  If that doesn't show up, that tells you the problem is with the trigger.

Otherwise, you have a script issue.  The most likely cause is that you're trying to load a scene that isn't listed in [the project's Build Settings.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html)  Double-check that the scene for the level you're loading is in there, or it won't get built into the project.  If the call to `LoadScene`/`LoadSceneAsync` is in your script before the call that is running the animation, then if it errors out due to the scene not being available, it would never reach the point where it plays the animation, which would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried playing around with the thing and I discovered by activating the mesh renderer that the trigger wall spawns in a different place than where it should be. I will attach some photos in a sec.

Comment: @DariusdXm All right.  So you know *what* the problem is.  Now the question is *why*.  See if you can verify whether it's starting out at that point and moving somehow, or if it originally spawns at the wrong position.  And work your way back from there...

Comment: It spawns there. I tried moving it down and to the right from the editor, but it still spawns there. This think took my whole day and I still could not fix it :)) At least I am getting closer to fixing it

Comment: All right.  So how is it spawning?  Is it directly part of the scene, or spawned in by a script?  Is it a child of another GameObject that might be doing something weird to it?

Comment: Thank you for your help Mason! I fixed the problem by making the trigger very big. Works fine now :))

Comment: All right.  If my help worked for you, please mark this as an accepted answer with the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.